# Reflection, Casting List<Int32> to IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that i need to reflect through an object properties and check values and other things. Everything seems to be working exception when i have a list and try to convert the item to an IEnumerable.

```
if (propType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
{
    var value = prop.GetValue(source);
    Type underlyingType = propType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    var enumerable = value as IEnumerable<object>;
    if(enumerable == null)
    {
        // problem here......
    }

    // Check the items in the list
}
```

The propType comes back as:

> FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"

The underlyingType comes back as:

`System.Int32`

This works when it is a list of custom classes, it just seems to be breaking when it is a value type.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: You can reason it out.  Accessing the list elements requires a conversion to object.  Simple of the list contains reference types, they directly inherit from *object*.  Definitely not simply for a value type, the element has to be *boxed*.  A boxing conversion requires code, that code isn't there.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that `int` is a value type makes the difference here. According to C# spec there must be a reference or identity conversion between generic types to make types variant-convertible:

> A type `T<A1, …, An>` is variance-convertible to a type `T<B1, …, Bn>` if
>   `T` is either an interface or a delegate type declared with the variant
>   type parameters `T<X1, …, Xn>`, and for each variant type parameter `Xi`
>   one of the following holds:
>
> - **`Xi` is covariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from `Ai` to `Bi`**
> - `Xi` is contravariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from `Bi` to `Ai`
> - `Xi` is invariant and an identity conversion exists from `Ai` to `Bi`

`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, so the line I marked is important. `Ai` in your case is `int` and `Bi` is `int`. There is no reference conversion from `int` to `object`, because `int` is not a reference type. There is also no identity conversion between these two, because they are not the same.

I don't know the entire context of your question, but you can use non-generic `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<object>`. They are pretty much the same. However, you might be facing an XY problem here, so it's hard to help you without knowing more about your case.